# Sponsor Portugal Proposal

Tags: feature-request, site-promotion

So, I proposed this site about Portugal (everything but language), and here there is a big audience of Portuguese users. Is there any way I can get this promoted here, since I'm sure a lot of people here are interested.

https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/110278/portugal

*I need one more follower by today, or else it will be removed! If your interested please, follow, ask a couple questions, and vote on some!*

Comment: "This proposal has been deleted."

Comment: @JorgeB. I didn't get enough followers in time. If you guys are interested I will open it back up.